# Given a HTTP request, is it possible to see which application originated it?

Tags: android, networking

Let's assume a scenario where all the network traffic is redirected through a local proxy, running on an Android device.

Within the proxy, is it possible to see which application (in terms of package name, application name, ..) originated that particular network call?

EDIT: apologies, I was short on details here. I'm referring to the HTTP protocol, hence a network call is just an HTTP request (either GET or POST) to some URL.

Comment: what is a "network call"? And no, it is not possible.

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific. Updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Bit of a workaround, actually, but **seems to be working** flawlessly.

I wrote a [simple Android library](https://github.com/dextorer/AndroidTCPSourceApp) to do so, if anyone wants to check it out. It is based on the fact that each socket is mapped as an entry on a file, called */proc/net/tcp* (or */proc/net/tcp6* for IPv6-based connections).

This means that, for each entry, we can read its port and its associated PID.

Basically, the main method of the library performs the following steps:

1. Receives a `Socket` object or the associated port (`Socket.getPort()`)
2. Parses the */proc/net/tcp* (or */proc/net/tcp6*) file, it looks for an entry with the given port
3. If an entry is found, the method extracts the PID from it
4. By calling the Android `PackageManager.getPackagesFromPid()` method with the newly found PID, we can obtain the unique information about the source application, such as package name and application version

The performances are quite good, since the */tcp** file is usually no longer than 50 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what info the app sends on the packet. If you're asking if network packets (btw you didn't specify which protocol you're referring to) have by default info about the app that sent it, then the answer is no.

But you can study the packets of a given set of apps, store this info in the proxy and then you can detect, given enough packets, the source app. Of course this won't yield info about apps you don't know.

EDIT: if it's an HTTP request, then usually the HTTP header includes information about the app that originates this request (e.g. browser version).

Comment: I'm referring to the HTTP protocol.

I expected a negative answer and I had already thought of the network calls "profiling", but this may lead to errors. For example, there may be two application that feature both Facebook SDK and AdMob SDK: given their network calls, I don't think it's possible to distinguish between the two of them.